# Conditional statements of rows and columns

Tags: r

I am trying a rather complex conditional statement in R that I need help with. I have a massive dataset (~1,450,000) different values.

I am trying to shave down the dataset with R by asking it a conditional statement: if multiple rows have the same values in column "date" AND if multiples rows have the same values in column "PageName", THEN give averages in columns "sst", "lat", and "long".

The code I have Frankensteined together so far is:

```
Combines_averages <- if(Combine_12$date == Combine_12$PageName{aggregate(Combine_12$sst, Combine_12$`location-lat`, Combine_12$`location-long`)}
```

Data:

```
Example_Data
# A tibble: 3 x 7
  animal_id   `location-lat` `location-long` date        sst month PageName
  <chr>                <dbl>           <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   
1 Alpha-626             30.5           -79.5 3/14/2020  22.2     3 ABCD    
2 Bravo-522             30.5           -79.5 3/14/2020  22.6     3 ABCD    
3 Charlie-389           30.5           -79.5 3/13/2020  22.4     3 BCAD  
4 Delta-720             30.5           -79.5 3/16/2020  22.8     3 CADB
5 Echo-550              30.5           -79.5 3/14/2020  22.2     3 ABCD
```

Comment: Please share some reproducible data using `dput(df)`? So we can help you better.

Comment: Show a little bit of sample input and the corresponding desired output. If you use `dput()` to share the data it is nice because it is copy/pasteable and includes class and structure info. E.g., `dput(Combine_12[1:10, c("date", "PageName", "sst", "location-lat", "location-long")])` for the first 10 rows of those columns--choose a suitable subset to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.